# How can i include views page in search results

Tags: search

I had created a view called "donor" with a page display. I includes nodes from content type "Donor-node". The title of "donor" views page is "donor wall". I created a view with type as content, which lists all nodes. An exposed search form with search term field. Is there any way to include "donor wall" page in this search results. If any one search for a key word donor, donor wall needs to list in result.

Comment: Just a shot from the hip really: Why don't you add the view to a node, and make that your "donor wall"?

Comment: That is a solution.But i need to rebuild it has a block and place this block in a page.Any other way through coding.

Comment: are you using the search_api module?

Answer (score 0):

Building a page via the views interface implements this page with the hook_menu. An entirely different approach from the nodes wich are saved in the database.

Views is essentially a query engine wich basically searches those database tables (and only one base table per view).

There is no real way to make a hook_menu implementation appear a node view. 
Ollies advice to put your view into a block and add it to a node is probably the best viable option.